# Visual Studio Published Application not Starting

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, clickonce

I am having trouble Publishing my Visual Studio Windows application. It's basically a WebBrowser and I would like to just have an installer so people are able to use it and install/uninstall. Everything says it works fine, but the application won't start when using the ClickOnce option. Is there another way or is there prerequisites that need to be defined?

Comment: Are you installing it on a clean system? If so do you know if .net is installed? It's been awhile since I used ClickOnce but I think there used to be a setting for including the .net framework you need.

Comment: I have installed it on both a clean Windows 10 system with nothing on it but Microsoft Word and also a Windows 10 machine with all the frameworks installed. Is there documentation on specific ones needed?

Comment: what happens when you navigate directly to the .exe and try to run it? Directions and discussion here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/3ab4fc8f-1212-424f-ac35-ba41be66e1ba/clickonce-application-doesnt-start?forum=winformssetup

Comment: I could not find the file path they were talking about. Is there something specific I need to add in my project's manifest? I am just using the 'Public Wizard' and assigning the paths to a server.

Comment: Did you check the Windows Event Viewer? If your application crashed, there would be a log for that.

Comment: @Torewin, BTW, file path they were talking about is obfuscated. So you will need to search it by your application name in  _C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Local_

Comment: @Zolbayar thanks for the help but I actually fixed it by creating an installer wizard for it!